# How to create minimum capacity .ps file

Tags: graphics

I have some images in my tex file. I had those images in .ps extension. When I create .ps file its capacity is more that 5mb. But I had to upload less that 1mb .ps file. So how can I do that ?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx! You don't need to add your name to your post, it appears automatically in the bottom right corner.

Answer (score 2):

Convert your `.ps` image to a `.pdf` using `ps2pdf.exe`. The size will be reduced significantly.

And if you want to import the resulting `.pdf` image, just import it from your (La)TeX main document using `\includegraphics[]{}` (from `graphicx.sty`) and compile using `pdflatex.exe`. Done!

## Edit 1

Online converter is also possible free of charge. Visit [this link](http://www.go2convert.com/). Make sure your pic is not confidential.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Miktex (I am not sure for Texlive), you may want to optimize your .eps/.ps figures with the `epstoeps` command line. Also, when you create a postscript figure with your favourite application, make sure to think about the number of points of your simulation, or the definition of included objects in general